# How do I get a path between quotes using regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a path between quotes that needs to be captured. I am very new to regular expressions and need some help figuring out how to do this.

Edit:

Sorry for not posting the string in the first place. that was silly of me. Here is the string:

```
"C:\Users\wner\Dropbox\Work\rts\rts\bin\Debug\rts.dll"
```

Now this is preceded by other strings and is followed by other strings, but I am able to single this out, however I do need the string within the quotes.

Comment: -1, show us what your string is and what you want to extract.  We aren't mind readers... yet.

Comment: Can you give us an exemple of input string you have and output string you want?

Comment: First step is to give us an example of the string that you are going to be parsing and what you expect to be extracted. A selection of examples is sometimes useful. Are there other quotes in the string such that we need to identify the correct ones. Is there a way to tell the path you want from anythign else that might look like a path?

Comment: And second step (or possibly the real first step) is to check whether it might not be easier to do with other tools. Often Regex is not the way to go (though it might be). :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you parsing command-line arguments?

Comment: i updated to be more specific

Comment: @Storm Kiernan Did you solve your problem ? If so, which solution have you taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove quote before and after your string:

```
string path = inputString.Trim('"');
```

If you want to remove all quotes:

```
string path = inputString.Replace("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see some code really, it sounds like your trying to do this???

```
string path = yourpathstring.Replace("\"", "");
```

This will remove the quotes and leave you with the path, not sure if this is what you want until there is some code.

Answer (score 0):

If regular expressions aren't *required*, you can you string.Split.

```
var split = path.Split("\"", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var unquotedPath = split[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much to go off of but this will do a non-greedy match of content between two double quotes:

```
"[^"\r\n]*"
```

So for the string:

> this "is\something" a test "again\something\else"

It would match `is\something` and `again\something\else`.